# Cannot access shared folder (samba)

Tags: permissions, samba, network-share

I have a Linux server (Linux1) where I have already configured folders to be shared out. It runs on RHEL 7.2. The configuration of my `/etc/samba/smb.conf` is as follows:

```
[sharing]
    path = /home/share
    guest ok = yes
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
```

Everything was working fine, I can access all the subfolders and files in the shared folder from my other Linux server (Linux2). The shared folder was previously mounted as `cifs` as `/mnt/share`.

I then restarted Linux1, disabled my firewall, and restarted the smb service.

From Linux2, I can see my shared folder and the subfolders, but when I tried to `ls` into a subfolder, it says `ls: reading directory /mnt/share/subfolder: Permission denied`.

I don't understand why this isn't working now.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that my SELinux was set to `Enforcing` on Linux1, and that was causing the permissions issue. After disabling it, I was able to access the subfolders and files again.

Answer (score 0):

You should not disable SELinux. A better idea would be to change the SELinux settings to allow access to your shares.

Running something like `chcon -t samba_share_t /home/share` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling selinux set the proper boolean and security context values as follows. (I assume "sharing" is samba share name)

```
setsebool -P samba_export_all_ro=1 samba_export_all_rw=1
getsebool -a | grep samba_export
semanage fcontext -at samba_share_t "/sharing(/.*)?"
restorecon /sharing
```

Also you may need to add some rules to allow traffic for samba.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=samba
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: firewall is disabled so there is no need to add any rule for that also.